# How to insert rows without duplicate key error

Tags: postgresql

There are two identical tables. The products in the first table have fewer filters than the products in the second table. More filters have been added to the second table.

Table A - product

[image: Table A - product]

Table B - product_new

[image: Table B - product_new]

Tried to update column rows according to documentation.

```
update main.product
  SET filter_id = main.product_new.filter_id
FROM main.product_new
WHERE main.product.product_id = product_new.product_id;
```

How to properly update rows of columns from second table to first table and avoid duplicate key error.
"duplicate key value violates unique constraint "product_pkey""

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: There are multiple rows in both tables that match your join condition, so it is unclear what you want the query to do. Please show us the result that you expect, as tabular text.

Comment: I need to update Table A  where there are only two filters, by adding filter_id from Table B

Comment: I can't just replace the tables. I just need to add the missing product filters.
Result, if the product from table A does not have filters that table B has, then add them.

Comment: Structure: DB_PRODUCT |  TABLES: main.product  (Table A), main.product_new (Table B)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to first query all rows that are not in `product` and then insert the result of that query directly:

```
INSERT INTO product(product_id, filter_id)
SELECT product_id, filter_id
FROM product_new
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT FROM product p
    WHERE p.product_id = product_new.product_id
      AND p.filter_id = product_new.filter_id)
```

Comment: Тhanks, I got all the values ​​from the second table, compared them and added the missing filters to the first table!